How can I suppress Tailwind base affecting certain wrapped MUI components?
In my project, most of the work is being done in Tailwind CSS, but there are some components that I use from MUI.
Since I use @base in my globals.css class, this affects some of the MUI components, despite me having wrapped them in ThemeRegistry.
I have tried to wrap these in ThemeRegistry from MUI hoping it would suppress the Tailwind style reset and apply the MUI normalisation instead, but it does not work at all.
<ThemeRegistry options={{ key: 'mui-theme', prepend: true }}>
  ...              
</ThemeRegistry>

My ThemRegistry file is as below.
// app/ThemeRegistry.tsx
"use client"
import createCache from "@emotion/cache"
import { useServerInsertedHTML } from "next/navigation"
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react"
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles"
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline"
import theme from "../src/theme"
import React from "react"

// This implementation is from emotion-js
// https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/2928#issuecomment-1319747902
export default function ThemeRegistry(props) {
  const { options, children } = props

  const [{ cache, flush }] = React.useState(() => {
    const cache = createCache(options)
    cache.compat = true
    const prevInsert = cache.insert
    let inserted = []
    cache.insert = (...args) => {
      const serialized = args[1]
      if (cache.inserted[serialized.name] === undefined) {
        inserted.push(serialized.name)
      }
      return prevInsert(...args)
    }
    const flush = () => {
      const prevInserted = inserted
      inserted = []
      return prevInserted
    }
    return { cache, flush }
  })

  useServerInsertedHTML(() => {
    const names = flush()
    if (names.length === 0) {
      return null
    }
    let styles = ""
    for (const name of names) {
      styles += cache.inserted[name]
    }
    return (
      <style
        key={cache.key}
        data-emotion={`${cache.key} ${names.join(" ")}`}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          // __html: styles,
          __html: options.prepend ? `@layer emotion {${styles}}` : styles
        }}
      />
    )
  })

  return (
    <CacheProvider value={cache}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        {children}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  )
}

My theme.js file is as follows:
import { createTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@mui/material/styles';

const rootElement = () => document.getElementById('__next');

// Create a theme instance.
const theme = responsiveFontSizes(
    createTheme({
        typography: {
            fontFamily: [
                'Inter',
                'Lexend',
                'Roboto',
                '-apple-system',
                'BlinkMacSystemFont',
                '"Segoe UI"',
                '"Helvetica Neue"',
                'Arial',
                'sans-serif',
                '"Apple Color Emoji"',
                '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
                '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
            ].join(','),
        },
        components: {
            MuiDialog: {
                defaultProps: {
                    container: rootElement,
                },
            },
        },
        palette: {
            primary: {
                main: '#546DE5',
            },
        },
    }),
);

export default theme;


